# Facebook Marketing API : Sharing Custom Audiences

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to create, add users, remove users to custom audiences and then share those audiences with other accounts. I have gotten all of these working except for the sharing part.

The api docs seem very vague on how to actually do this. Here is what it says:

> Share your custom audience with business objects at
>   '/custom-audience/share_with_objects'

Does anyone know how to do this through the API? I imagine you'd need the AD_ACCOUNT_ID and the CUSTOM_AUDIENCE_ID in some capacity.

for reference that quoted line above is from here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api
under the header Building a Custom Audience

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It links to `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-audience/share_with_objects/`, which only returns a 404. File a documentation bug, and ask them to please fix the broken link.  https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you want to do but the documentation says how you can Create and Share a custom audience with other advertiser accounts.[Reference here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-audience/adaccounts/). You have to POST on this endpoint `/{custom_audience_id}/adaccounts` and specify the `owner ad account` and the `recipient ad account`. Please, check the documentation for more information. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2018; Custom Audiences can now be shared [only between Businesses](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/499290663823687?id=2469097953376494) (it is mandatory for both parties to have `BusinessManager`)

[How to Share Custom Audience Lists](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/499290663823687?id=2469097953376494)

> Both entities must have a Business Manager

[Share Custom Audiences between Business Managers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/business-asset-management/guides/share-custom-audiences)

> Since 2018, in order to share a Custom Audience between Business
>   Managers, such businesses should establish an audience sharing
>   relationship as follows. You need Business Manager admin permission to
>   request a relationship to share an audience. If two Business Managers
>   have already established the relationship, then an advertiser can
>   directly share the audience with the other business. See also
>   Reference, Custom Audience and Reference, Custom Audience Shared
>   Account Info.

---

And while `marketing-api` [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/business-asset-management/guides/share-custom-audiences) have improved a bit, but still completely lack the *get-started-in-5-min* crispness

> To create a relationship, make this call, to a specific custom_audience_id:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/{custom_audience_id}/adaccounts?adaccounts=[<ad_account_id>]&relationship_type=[<relationship_type>]
```

and while nowhere they've specified what is this `relationship_type`, I peeked into their [`java-business-sdk`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-java-business-sdk) and found [this](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-java-business-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/com/facebook/ads/sdk/OfflineConversionDataSet.java#L3528)

```
public static enum EnumRelationshipType {
      @SerializedName("AD_MANAGER")
      VALUE_AD_MANAGER("AD_MANAGER"),
      @SerializedName("AGENCY")
      VALUE_AGENCY("AGENCY"),
      @SerializedName("AGGREGATOR")
      VALUE_AGGREGATOR("AGGREGATOR"),
      @SerializedName("AUDIENCE_MANAGER")
      VALUE_AUDIENCE_MANAGER("AUDIENCE_MANAGER"),
      @SerializedName("OTHER")
      VALUE_OTHER("OTHER"),
      ;
      ..
```